# How to set two filtering values in one column of links in an interactive report? (Oracle Apex 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

I need help creating a link in Oracle APEX.

I have two Interactive Report pages created in Oracle APEX.

The first page is an Interactive Report for a list of cats. When clicking on that link, filter the second page's Interactive Report by the `"fur color"` column. Furthermore, I want to always be `"white"` in addition to the color of the selected row.
I try 2 types of methods to create a link in Link Builder.

1. `Name = IR_FUR_COLOR, Value = &P18_FUR_COLOR.` and more one line `Value = White`
2. `Name = IR_FUR_COLOR, Value = &P18_FUR_COLOR.,White`

But they did not work.

How should I do it? Does anyone help me?

Thank you for watching this question!

Comment: Perhaps only "eq" operation can be set in Link Builder? If "In" operation is available, this question may be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link Builder should contain only

- Name: `IR_FUR_COLOR`, Value: `&P18_FUR_COLOR`

Modify the second Interactive Report's query so that its `where` clause looks like this:

```
where fur_color in ('white', :IR_FUR_COLOR)
```

which means that it'll always filter `white` color, along with any color you pass from the previous page.

---

There are variations to that approach; for example, you could create another (hidden) item on the 2nd page and pass `white` to it and then

```
where fur_color in (:HIDDEN_FUR_COLOR, :IR_FUR_COLOR)
```